# Помогите со связным списком на Java

Tags: java

Нужно удалить повторяющиеся элементы связного списка списка. Вывести сначала исходный связный список, затем уже с удалением. Я вот написал код(преподаватель проверил и сказал что он правильный), но он просто заполняет список, но теперь нужно как-то сделать, чтобы он удалял одинаковые числа 
Мой код:

```
    //Первый файл 
public class TestArray {

        public static void init (double[] values) {
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++)
                values[i]=Math.random()*100;
        }
        public static void print (double[] values) {
            for (double d: values)
                System.out.printf("%10.2f", d);
                System.out.println();
        }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        double[] values= new double [10];
        init(values);
        print(values);
        Array.Pair p=Array.minMax(values);
        System.out.printf("min=%10.2f\n", p.getfirst());
        System.out.printf("max=%10.2f\n", p.getsecond());

   }
}
//Второй файл
public class Array {

        public static class Pair {
            private double first, second;
            public Pair (double f, double s) {
                first=f;
                second=s;
            }
            public double getfirst() {
                return first;
            }
            public double getsecond() {
                return second;
            }
        }

        public static Pair minMax (double[] values) {
            double min, max;
            min=max=values[0];
            for (double d: values) {
                if (min>d)
                    min=d;
                if (max<d)
                    max=d;
            }
            return new Pair (min, max);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Кхм, кхм, не вижу ни "связности", ни "списка". И повторяющихся элементов, скорее всего, не будет.

Comment: Да вроде всё есть, код компилировал и он выводит связный список

Comment: Так, дело обстоит хуже, чем я думал. Что Вы понимаете под словами "связный список"? Особенно интересует слово "связный".

Comment: Ну на сколько я понял, это список в котором элемент ссылается на каждый следующий элемент. Этим кодом он создаётся вроде как  public Pair (double f, double s) {
                first=f;
                second=s;
            }

Comment: Но я могу ошибаться, если нет, то прошу поправить меня и код.Я только изучаю эту тему, сложная

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA  Попробуйте сделать в интернете поиск на слова "связный список".

Comment: Только что компилировал код на javatutor и структура такая же, что и на схемах в википедии по вашей ссылке

Comment: @Дмитрий ну вот же: "Принципиальным преимуществом перед массивом является структурная гибкость". А у вас массив. Значит он не может быть связным списком.

Comment: Структура чего? В связном списке элемент списка содержит ссылку на следующий элемент, а тот на следующий элемент, и так далее. Ваш класс с двумя числами не имеет к этому никакого отношения.

Comment: В java реализацией связного списка является класс LinkedList. Найдите в интернете, как он работает, и сразу поймете, в чем дело. А еще лучше, если вы прочитаете статью на вики до конца